# CSS div height based on height of Content div

Tags: css

How can I make the Green and  the red div in this jsfiddle expand with the content of the blue div?

http://jsfiddle.net/4ZJVh/

```
    <html style="height: 100%" >
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </head>
    <body style="height: 100%; background-color: grey">
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div style="background-color: fuchsia; height: 50px; width: 100%; float: left; "></div>
            <div style="background-color: green; min-height: 100%; width: 20%; float: left; ">oo</div>
            <div style="background-color: blue; float: left; width:60%; height: 100%" >            
             test
            </br> test
            </br> test
            </br> test
            </br> test
            </br> test
            </br> test
            </br> test
            </br> test
            </br> test
            </br> test
            </br> test
            </br> test
            </br>
            </div>
            <div style="background-color: red; float: left; width: 20%; height: 200px;"></div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main issue you have is that your `form` element has no `height` set, so there is no height for the other divs to inherit.

Give your form a fixed `height` or `height:100%;` and it should work.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" style="height:100%;">
```

You should also think about separating your CSS and HTML - Inline CSS is very hard to keep track of, I have done this for you on the jsfiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/4ZJVh/2/